# RC oscillator to measure capacitance with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, analog, adc, measurement

I want to measure capacitance sensors with a microcontroller.
One way to do this is to use comparators and measure charging time.

As I cannot (and don't want to) use comparators I thought to build RC oscillator to have it generate sine wave, then I connect this sine wave to the digital input of the uC (its latch will convert this to a square wave) and I will count impulses.

1. What is the simplest RC circuit to generate this wave?
2. And how to convert number of impulses to the capacitance (given known R)?

Comment: You could use `555` part to generate a square wave and measure it's frequency.

Comment: You could use a 555 (as @EugeneSh. just got in with before me!) but a 555 is just two comparators with resistors and a latch in one chip - does that break your 'no comparators' rule?

Comment: BTW, *..As I cannot (and don't want to) use comparators..* - why is that?

Comment: Using a unknown capacitor as the frequency-setting component of a oscillator, then measuring the resulting frequency can be a valid way to measure the capacitance.  However, your statement that you cannot use comparators makes no sense at all.  This is therefore either due to silly religious reasons, because you want to steer answers a certain way even though others meet the requirements, or this is homework.  Closing either way.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Homework? Oh really? The fact that you cannot think of a use case and you can't make sense doesn't mean it's "religious" or homework.
The reason is simple -I have uC with at least 20 generic channels (some digital, some digital / analog inputs). User can connect different things (ICs, sensors and so on) amongst capacitance sensor. The problem is that I don't know what user will choose to connect, I'm designing universal device, so user may connect 20 cap. sensor (unlikely). I have only few comp. on uC and cannot place 20 of them for each channel. While one resistor for channel seems rational.

Answer (score 2):

The method you describe would require you to somehow modulate a digital pin with an LC circuit (with a DC offset to bring it above ground) until you reach resonance or have sufficient oscillation amplitude to measure the period. You could pump the LC pair and interrupt on the edges after you pass it through a digital buffer of some sort then time between interrupts. 1/f = 1/(2*pi*(L*C)^0.5). L in known and T is measured (T = 1/f) so the micro can calculate with fairly good precision from there. This actually seems like a very cheap, albeit fuzzy way to solve the problem. The amplitude of the resonant tank circuit waveform will be finicky and you will most likely need to amplify it to the point of clipping before going to the buffer, at which point it becomes more complex than using a comparator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYVPIa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, Using a comparator seems to be a much more reliable way to accomplish this task. If you need very fine precision, you can use a very large resistor with respect to the capacitor of interest therefore yielding a large time constant [(t = RC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant). Next I would choose a microcontroller with an analog comparator peripheral such as the ATmega or ATtiny and set the compare input to a voltage divider set at 63.2% of the rail of the system. 
[image]
*from ATtiny85 datasheet
Then you can use a timer that starts up counting when you turn the pin attached to the resistor on and wait for an interrupt from the analog comparator and look at the timer counter value. See the attached schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f33EC4.png)</sup>

The precision will be dictated by the frequency of the timer you are running, the latency of your software and of course component tolerance. You may need to cascade timer overflows to a variable in RAM to generate longer periods as well. This method yields really simple math since you just are sampling tau with a known R value, so to solve for C its just tau/R.